# Can we write stored procedures in SQLite on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, stored-procedures

Can anyone tell me how to write stored procedures in SQLite on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No...
From: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> SQLite has had to **sacrifice** other characteristics that some people find useful, such as high concurrency, fine-grained access control, a rich set of built-in functions, **stored procedures**, esoteric SQL language features, XML and/or Java extensions, tera- or peta-byte scalability, and so forth.